# "Secret Registration" providers list for filtering WHOIS API results

Tags: whois

I'm using a WHOIS API to pull information up on companies that register domain names. However, I don't want results where the domain is registered through a proxy such as "Domains By Proxy."

Is there a comprehensive or otherwise decent list of providers I can put into my code to filter out those results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that a decent list of providers exists, unfortunately. (At least not one that is publicly available.)

The trouble is that there is a not insignificant number of services offering WHOIS anonymity. A while ago, looking at a set of around 250,000 WHOIS records I found around 100 such providers. These were identified by filtering out keywords (*proxy*, *priva-*, etc.) and then picking out relevant names by eye. I'm sure I just found the 100 most obviously named ones!

Another part of the difficulty in compiling a list is deciding what type of entity should count as a privacy provider.

You're probably aware that there are registrars and registries which allow domain holders privacy by default. For example, some WHOIS records will show the registrar's contact information only. Also, as often happens, a large legal firm or marketing agency might take ownership of domains on behalf of a client but use *its* own details instead...

I'm not sure if it will be of any use to you, but here are the e-mail addresses of some of the most frequently used privacy protection services found in the (perhaps not very representative) sample of records I mentioned earlier. I estimate that between them they account for well over 90% of domains registered to privacy services.

```
[name]@domainsbyproxy.com
[name]@whoisguard.com
contact@privacyprotect.org
proxy@whoisprotectservice.com
[name]@domainidshield.com
whoisproxy@value-domain.com
privacy@whoisprivacyprotection.info
private-whois-service@tjvps.com
[name]@domaindiscreet.com
[name]@protecteddomainservices.com
[name]privacyguardian.org
whoisprivacyprotect@whoisservices.cn
whoisagent@west263.com
[name]@privacy.above.com
contact@myprivateregistration.com
privacy@dynadot.com
whoisprivacy@everdns.com
[name]@1and1-private-registration.com
[name]@proxy.dreamhost.com
```

`[name]` is usually the domain name in question or a random string of characters.