# Check if domain has WHOIS privacy

Tags: api, privacy, whois

I use an API to get Whois data of a domain

Sample response from API:

For domain 1:

```
registrant_contact":{
"full_name": "WHOISGUARD PROTECTED",
"company_name": "WHOISGUARD, INC.", 
}
```

For domain 2:

```
"registrant_contact":{
"full_name": "Whois Privacy Protection Service by onamae.com",
"company_name": "Whois Privacy Protection Service by onamae.com", 
}
```

registrant_contact.full_name may vary depending on the provider

Is there an easy or programmatic way to determine if domain has WHOIS privacy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whois Privacy is not a standard service. This is offered by multiple companies, including registrars themselves, with varying degree of service and features.

It can also be done on the registry level in some cases, specially in ccTLDs for individuals.

So, besides listing all specific text strings you can get back, I do not see a solution to your problem, except some heuristics (like the form of email addresses or postal addresses, etc.)

See this other answer for some heuristics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25233555/6368697

Answer (score 0):

Many domain registrars offer services called "domain privacy," or “private registration” that remove your personal contact information from the WHOIS record. Because of that, you cant get response for some domain. If you want to query the domain, you can use our whois tool http://www.yazilimdersi.info/araclar/whois-sorgulama. Our tool displaying domain information, domain owner, dates of domain with the remaining day.